# jQuery stacked column chart with both negative and positive values

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, charts

Is it possible to have a jQuery stacked column chart with both negative and positive values?

I have been using [**Steve Fenton's jQuery Charts** *(Vertical Bars)*](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/charts.html) however am unable to produce both a positive and negative value like the image below:

[image]

Here is a jsfiddle of what I currently have: **http://jsfiddle.net/jMXMb/**

Any ideas, links, solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just apply some css to get your negative bars... but the values can't themselves be negative =(

```
#example2b + h3 + .chartscontainer .chartsbar {
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
}
```

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jMXMb/1/). If you do need negative values, and the numbers inside the bars switched, I think it will require some code changes to the plugin. Or some more creative css...

Comment: Nice thinking @fudgey, it's a great solution! Pitty there isn't a jQuery plugin/fix for this sort of chart.

Comment: By adding some CSS within the jQuery plugin I was able to separate the elements and position them based on your markup. Thanks heaps for the head start and smart thinking =D